# Is waring's function strictly increasing?

Tags: number-theory

For every positive integer $n$, let $w(n)$ be the least positive integer $m$ such that every positive integer is the sum of at most $m$ $n$-th powers of positive integers. Is this function $w$ strictly increasing? If not, is it at least increasing?

Comment: The accepted answer below says that the answer is "conjecturally" yes. But it is easy to prove it unconditionally. The computation of $w(k)$ certainly gives $w(k) \ge 2^k$ for $k \ge 2$ and $w(k) \le 2^k + (3/2)^k + (4/3)^k$. From this it is obvious that $w(k+1) > w(k)$ unconditionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably strictly increasing. It is an open problem whether $\displaystyle w(n)=2^n+\left\lfloor\frac{3^n}{2^n}\right\rfloor-2$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

The formula is true for all $n$ as long as there is no $n$ obeying the inequality $\displaystyle2^n\left\{\frac{3^n}{2^n}\right\}+\left\lfloor\frac{3^n}{2^n}\right\rfloor>2^n$. Kurt Mahler showed that there can only be finitely many $n$ that satisfy this inequality. Jeffrey M. Kubina and Marvin C. Wunderlich showed that if there is an $n$ obeying this inequality, then it satisfies $n>471,600,000$.

Answer (score 1):

It is conjectured that $$g(k)=2^k+\lfloor (\frac{3}{2})^k\rfloor-2$$

for all $k\ge 2$. If so, $g(k)$ is clearly strictly increasing.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem